# git status in parent module not showing new commits in submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Why is the parent module's status showing no changes? What am I missing? The submodule is 2 commits ahead of the the commit returned by ls-tree in the parent module but it doesn't show up in status and commit -a says there are no changes. .git/info/exclude has no uncommented lines.

```
/Repo/Submodule (master)$ git log -3 --format="%H"
a210765353b5bbbdd5bd82b5b872b7d4c1fcb322
b39b3942fcf0bf08d98e2d7767a063c2f5c4ba95
fb1721d7bf78ff7c2182a7d33c0976544c8340d3

/Repo/Submodule (master)$ cd ..

/Repo (master)$ git ls-tree HEAD Submodule
160000 commit fb1721d7bf78ff7c2182a7d33c0976544c8340d3  Submodule

/Repo (master)$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

/Repo (master)$ git --version
git version 2.33.0.windows.1
```

Comment: At this point just looking for suggestions for where to look if I see this again. I pulled my changes to the submodule on a different system and the parent module status showed the changes and was able to commit them. I then did a pull in the original location and now everything matches up like it should. Though who knows if it will work next time I add a commit there.

Comment: You can configure how `git status` should behave with submodules. The default should be to say that the submodule has new commits, though, if its `HEAD` (rev-parse result - `a2107...` in your case) doesn't match the index value (`fb172...`, I think, based on your output); I'm not sure why you didn't get that.

Comment: @Joseph Were you able to find a solution to this? Currently facing the same issue

Comment: No. I deleted it and cloned again and it went away. I think it must have gotten corrupted somehow.